# Выведите всю информацию о пользователе из таблицы Users, кто является владельцем самого дорого жилья (таблица Rooms)

Tags: sql, подзапрос

[image: Мое решение]

Пытаюсь выполнить такую задачу со скалярным подзапросом, тренажер sql-academy ругается, говорит, что неверно

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас владелец может иметь несколько комнат, и соответственно нужно найти суммарную стоимость для каждого владельца.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from Users
where Users.id = (select owner_id from Rooms order by price desc limit 1)
```

справился с задачей таким образом

Answer (score 1):

Вижу, что уже разобрались, но внесу дополнительно еще и понимание. В условиях задачи делается акцент на то, что надо вывести **всю информацию именно о пользователе**, но когда мы выбираем в SELECT все столбцы и потом делаем JOIN, в выдачу попадает вся информация и из другой таблицы. Следовательно надо исключить ее из финального результата. Решить можно следующим образом:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM Users u
    JOIN Rooms r ON u.id = r.owner_id
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM Rooms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Час думал, что я делаю не так. Сэкономлю время трудягам, которые в будущем столкнутся с данным вопросом. Постараюсь подробно ответить.
Финальный код:

Select Users.* FROM users
JOIN Rooms ON Rooms.owner_id = Users.id
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM Rooms)

Пояснения:
**Во-первых**, ставим **"звёздочку"**, тем самым мы хотим получить все записи. **Для выбора конкретной таблицы ставим "Users."** Точку не забываем) Получается все значения из таблицы Users. ***Если просто "звёздочку" поставите без указания конкретной таблицы, то он ещё вам выдаст результаты из Rooms, а это по условиям задачи не требуется, поэтому может выдавать сообщение о неверном решении.***
**Во-вторых**, делаем подзапрос на ценник для таблицы **Rooms**. Таким образом получится скалярное значение, удовлетворяющие критерии запроса.
**В-третьих**, связываем обе таблицы через многотабличный запрос **JOIN**. По умолчанию, будет являться внутренним.
Надеюсь, поможет кому-нибудь :)

Answer (score 0):

Можете еще посмотреть на такой вариант:

```
select * from users where id = 
  (select owner_id from Rooms where price = (select max(price) from Rooms));
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]